# How to implement the same claim for different departments

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, jwt, claims-based-identity

I am building a webapp that uses windows authentication and supplements it with roles and claims from a local DB. I am planning to use a JWT to store this information once the user is authenticated.

Our organization has different departments and I am wondering how I could go about implementing roles/claims in this case.

For example:

Bob is an admin for both department A and B.

In Bob's principle, how could I add claims that reflect this. I.E.

```
bob.claims = new claim[] {

    new claim() { department = "A", role = Roles.Admin },
    new claim() { department = "B", role = Roles.Admin }
}
```

Then I could do something like:

```
[Authorize(IsInDepartmentRole(Department: "A", Role: Roles.Admin)]
```

Keep in mind this is all pseudo-code.

I realize storing this info in a JWT might not work out, so I am willing to move to an in memory cache (or similar).

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this information as claims, but since a claim consists of a type-value, the approach in the pseudo code will not work.

There are some options, but I would suggest the following:

```
new Claim { Type = "DepartmentRole", Value = "A;Admin" }
```

In any case, keep the type a constant. The value can be split into A and Admin, corresponding to department and role. You can add multiple claims of the same type.

Now you can define a policy:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AdminOfDeptA", policy => 
                                      policy.RequireClaim("DepartmentRole", "A;Admin"));
}
```

The authorize attribute only allows strings as parameter, so again your pseudocode won't work. But you can now use this, where AdminOfDeptA is the configured policy:

```
[Authorize("AdminOfDeptA")]
```

If you don't want to define all combinations, you may want to take a look at [resource-based authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased?tabs=aspnetcore2x).