# Send custom parameter to IdentityServer when token refreshing

Tags: angular, authentication, identityserver4, openid, openid-connect

Is it possible to pass a custom parameter to identity server when the token is renewed/refreshed?

In my case, I have identityserver4 and an Angular client with oidc-client framework, where the client logs in identity using the code flow with PKCE from OAuth2 and OpenIdConnect.

The idea of this application is to be able to log in with the same user in the same program but in different companies, so, when the user changes the company he will have to refresh the token to get different roles for that company.

At the moment, when the client logs in at identity by introducing his credentials, he passes the company from the Angular client in the following way:

```
  private _authNavStatusSource = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  authNavStatus$ = this._authNavStatusSource.asObservable();

  private manager = new UserManager(getClientSettings());
  user: User | null;

  public httpOptions;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private configService: ConfigService) {
    super();

    this.manager.getUser().then(user => {
      this.user = user;
      this._authNavStatusSource.next(this.isAuthenticated());
    });

    this.manager.events.addUserLoaded(user => {
      this.user = user;
    });

    this.subscribeevents();

  }

  login(company: string) {
    this.manager.settings.extraQueryParams = {companyCode: company};
    return this.manager.signinRedirect();
  }

  async completeAuthentication() {
      this.user = await this.manager.signinRedirectCallback();
      this._authNavStatusSource.next(this.isAuthenticated());
      console.log('Login complete');
  }

...

  async signout() {
    await this.manager.signoutRedirect();
  }
```

This way in Identity Server AccountController I have access to this parameter from:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginInputModel model, string button)
{

var context = await _interaction.GetAuthorizationContextAsync(model.ReturnUrl);

…

Claim[] additionalLocalClaims =
    {
       new Claim("companyCode", context.Parameters["companyCode"])
    };

var context = await _interaction.GetAuthorizationContextAsync(model.ReturnUrl);

Claim[] additionalLocalClaims =
    {
       new Claim("companyCode", context.Parameters["companyCode"])
    };

…
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(user.SubjectId, user.UserName, props,additionalLocalClaims);
```

Then I add this claim with the company to make it available in my CustomProfileConfiguration

This way from the CustomProfileConfiguration I have access to the company and can get the roles of this user in this company.

```
public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {
    var companyCode = context.Subject.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "companyCode");
```

The problem comes when the user changes companies and the token has to be refreshed to take on the new roles for the new company.

If the following `signout()` method is executed on the client side, the user is completely logged out and to enter the other company he has to re-enter the credentials (which will be the same ones he had already entered).

**The objective would be to refresh the token by passing the new company to identityserver without having to introduce the credentials again using the cookie that identityserver creates.**

I hope I explained myself well and that you can help me, thank you very much!

Comment: Why not include all claims for all companies? Regardless which one is the current company, the user is authorized.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg Hi! Yes, I thought this. But the problem is how I can manage the roles and know the company when apply the policy on the backend side.

Comment: You can add a discriminator in the claim as I've mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48351370). Or use claimtypes that hold information about this, check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44307473). Something like that or a combination of both answers. Alternative is to remove these type of claims from the access token and use a different source for user authorization.

Answer (score 0):

If your Identity Server can work out what company the user wants to log in under, you can set `UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh` on the client and IS will generate new claims every time the refresh token is used. Then you need to revoke the current access token and force the client use the refresh token.

Documentation is here:
https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/refresh_tokens.html?highlight=UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh

If you rely on the information coming from the client (about which company to use), you will probably have to create your own implementation of the `RefreshTokenService` by implementing `IRefreshTokenService` interface. Then you can pass another query parameter to the refresh token endpoint, read it from the `HttpContext` and adjust the behavior appropriately. It is a fair amount of work though.

https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/refresh_tokens.html?highlight=UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh#customizing-refresh-token-behavior

Another alternative I can think of is writing a middleware that will listen for the refresh token endpoint calls, will try to pick up a custom parameter, store it to some cache storage and then read it in the `ProfileService` and generate the claims accordingly (assuming you have the `UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh` turned on).